# Expected value of the inner product equals l2-norm?

Tags: integration, normed-spaces, expected-value, inner-products

Referring to [Butucea](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0612361v3.pdf#page=10) (14), I have given $(Y_i)_{i\in \mathbb N}$ iid. with Lebesgue-density $p$, a kernel $K$ and the scalar product $\langle f,g\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\overline{g}(x)\mathrm d x$. In (14) it states:
$$\mathbb E(d_n)=\mathbb E(\langle K(\cdot-Y_1),K(\cdot-Y_2)\rangle)=\|K\ast p\|_2^2$$
I have a problem with taking the expected value of the scalar product.
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E(\langle K(\cdot-Y_1),K(\cdot-Y_2)\rangle)&=\mathbb E(\int_{-\infty}^\infty K(x-Y_1)\overline{K(x-Y_2)}\mathrm d x)\\
    &=\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(y)\int_{-\infty}^\infty K^2(x-y) \mathrm d x \mathrm d y\\
    &\overset{?}{=}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty (p(x) K(x-y))^2 \mathrm d x \mathrm d y=\|K\ast p\|_2^2
\end{align*}
I'm not sure how the $p^2(x)$ appears at the "?".

Comment: Shouldn't there be $y_1$ and $y_2$ after applying $\mathbb{E}$ instead of one $y$, and thus it should be an integral on $\mathbb{R}^2$? That'd also make $p(y_1)p(y_2)$ appear (thanks to independence) instead of just $p(y)$, thus closer to the needed square. Do take my comment with a grain of salt though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bruno B is right. Notice that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are iid random variables.

\begin{align*} &\mathbb{E} \langle K(\cdot -Y_1), K(\cdot -Y_2) \rangle \\ &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} p(y_1) p(y_2) K(x-y_1) \overline{K(x-y_2)} dx dy_1 dy_2 \end{align*}

You should arrive at the desired result by factoring this into two integrals (like $\int (\int \cdots dy_1)(\int \cdots dy_2) dx$ ), one with $y_1$ and one with $y_2$.